# Fastest data structure with default values for undefined indexes?

Tags: data-structures, defaultdict, game-maker

I'm trying to create a 2d array where, when I access an index, will return the value. However, if an undefined index is accessed, it calls a callback and fills the index with that value, and then returns the value.

The array will have negative indexes, too, but I can overcome that by using 4 arrays (one for each quadrant around 0,0).

Comment: In what language - Game Maker (GML) or python? Your tags are contradicting a bit in that respect.

Comment: Any language, it's more of a general question.

Comment: you cannot use negative indexes in GameMaker

Comment: Hence why I said I can overcome that using 4 arrays, one for x,y, one for -x,y, one for x,-y, and one for -x,-y.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Matrix class that relies on tuples and dictionary, with the following behavior :

```
from collections import namedtuple
2DMatrixEntry = namedtuple("2DMatrixEntry", "x", "y", "value")
matrix = new dict()
defaultValue = 0

# add entry at 0;1
matrix[2DMatrixEntry(0,1)] = 10.0

# get value at 0;1
key = 2DMatrixEntry(0,1)
value = {defaultValue,matrix[key]}[key in matrix]
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably too broad for stackoverflow. - There is not a generic "one size fits all" solution for this, and the results depend a lot on the language used (and standard library).

There are several problems in this question. First of all let us consider a 2d array, we say this is simply already part of the language and that such an array grows dynamically on access. If this isn't the case, the question becomes really language dependent.

Now often when allocating memory the language automatically initializes the spots (again language dependent on how this happens and what the best method is, look into RAII). Though I can foresee that actual calculation of the specific cell might be costly (compared to allocation). In that case an interesting thing might be so called "two-phase construction". The array has to be filled with tuples/objects. The default construction of an object sets a bit/boolean to false - indicating that the value is not ready. Then on acces (ie a `get()` method or a `operator()` - language dependent) if this bit is false it constructs, else it just reads.

---

Another method is to use a dictionary/key-value map. Where the key would be the coordinates and the value the value. This has the advantage that the problem of construct-on-access is inherit to the datastructure (though again language dependent). The drawback of using maps however is that lookup speed of a value changes from O(1) to O(logn). (The actual time is widely different depending on the language though).

---

At last I hope you understand that how to do this depends on more specific requirements, the language you used and other libraries. In the end there is only a single data structure that is in each language: a long sequence of unallocated values. Anything more advanced than that depends on the language.